# Should I add the same tools:context code to each XML size file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Inside my "com.example.myname.appname file I have my "AddContacts.java" class.

So I created a activity_addcontacts.xml file and activity_addcontacts.xml(large) and activity_addcontacts.xml(Xlarge) xml files for different size devices.

Inside my XML design for the regular xml file it states:

```
 tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.AddContacts"
```

So the above links my "AddContacts.java" code to this "normal" size xml file. However, this code line is NOT automatically presented in large XML file and Xlarge XML file.

Should I add this code line myself or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

`tools:context` is completely optional. This is used by Lint and Android Studio layout editor.
This attribute declares which activity this layout is associated with by default.

This enables features in the editor or layout preview that require knowledge of the activity, such as what the layout theme should be in the preview and where to insert onClick handlers when you make those from a quickfix

Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Comment: So without tools:context, Android Studio will load the right XML size file for the right device? It won't just always load all my devices with the regular XML file for like the Tablet sizes (even though I created large XML sizes for tablet)? I don't have android device yet so I can't test, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @iBEK  tools:context is useful in preview layout editor of Android Studio. So If you are checking in preview layout editor then themes might not work properly. Everything will work fine on emulator and real device.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [Tools Attributes Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolscontext):

> tools:context
>   Intended for: Any root
>
> Used by: Lint, Android Studio layout editor
>
> This attribute declares which activity this layout is associated with
>   by default. This enables features in the editor or layout preview that
>   require knowledge of the activity, such as what the layout theme
>   should be in the preview and where to insert onClick handlers when you
>   make those from a quickfix (figure 2).
>
> [image]

You can add the code if you want the preview with the activity theme or if you have the `onClick` attribute. But it's not a mandatory. Slightly of of the topic but I think need to be told, don't use `onClick` attribute in your xml code. Why? Because when we using `onClick` in xml code, we mixing a UI code with logic code which is bad. In the long run, it will be a maintenance nightmare.